# Making a column for wet and dry seasons

Tags: r

I was wondering how to I add a column to my data frame that has either wet or dry season? I made a months column and I was trying to say that the numbers that are between 5 and 11 are considered dry while everything else is considered wet. I am new to R

I tried df$season=within(df{season=ifelse(month=5:11, dry,wet)})

I want that if the month is greater than 5 and less than 11 than it is considered dry and if it not one of those than it is et

Comment: I don't get what's going on with your syntax, but I think you should take a step back to revisit that first. Extract data frame columns with `[[` or `$`, not `{}`. Do logical comparisons with `==`, not `=`. `5:11` gives the vector `5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11`, but just checking against it doesn't tell you a value is contained in that vector; `%in%` would be one way to do that. And strings need quotation marks, or they're assumed to be variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect and you need to put quotes around dry and wet. This should work :

```
df$season <- ifelse(df$month %in% 5:11, "dry", "wet")
```

Answer (score 0):

Also worth looking into the dplyr functions, particularly the `mutate` and `case_when` functions:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(months = c(1:12))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(season = case_when(
    months > 5 & months < 11 ~ "dry",
    TRUE ~ "wet"
  ))
```

Comment: `case_when` with only 2 conditions doesn't really do anything that `ifelse` can't, does it? This ends up being more verbose and less clear than just `ifelse(months %in% 5:11, "dry", "wet")`

Comment: absolutely – I just like the flexibility of vectorising multiple if_else statements if I develop an interest in more than 2 conditions